# Infinite Scrolling Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll, ondemand

I Found these [demos](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) for infinite scrolling using Jquery, but I don't know how can I use them since their source is not provided. 
If anyone fond them would you please clear the issue ?

I tried this code for Demo 5,  but it didn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function lastAddedLiveFunc()
    {
        $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');

        $.get("loadmore.php", function(data){
            if (data != "") {
                //console.log('add data..');
                $(".items").append(data);
            }
            $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
        });
    };

    //lastAddedLiveFunc();
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
        var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

        if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
         //console.log('scroll bottom');
         lastAddedLiveFunc();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="items">
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>

   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>
   <li>content</li>                   
  </ul>

<div id="lastPostsLoader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see the samples and they all included the `<script src='...'></script>`. You should be able to find out which file to include and how to use it.

Comment: I tried it but something is missing

Comment: I see that you only included the `jquery-1.9.0.min.js`. The js of the plugin you are using should be included too, say, `jquery.masonry.min.js` for demo 1.

Comment: But those were required for the first plugin, this is the 5th one.

Comment: This is **much** better script ☞ https://github.com/yairEO/infinite

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
function lastAddedLiveFunc(){
    $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigLoader.gif">');

    $.get("loadmore.php", function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            //console.log('add data..');
            $(".items").append(data);
        }
        $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){

      var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
      var  scrolltrigger = 0.95;

      if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
       //console.log('scroll bottom');
       lastAddedLiveFunc();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: have you tried with `scrollHeight`? and are there any error in the console.

Comment: Yes an error shows : file://.../loadmore.php
Failed to load resource: Resource failed to load ..... 
I don't know what's scrollHeight.

Comment: are you testing this on local webserver like `wamp` or `xampp`?

Comment: No Just Regular html page

Comment: then you have to test it on `webserver` like `wamp` or `xamp` because `$.get()` is a shorthand ajax method.

Comment: Isn't there a method to prevent using php ?

Comment: You can use json structure for this.

Comment: Great, I'll make my website with Json. But If I want to test this plugin with just some static data, would this be possible ?

Comment: absolutely try with json.

Comment: Do you know where can I find loadmore.php ?

Comment: I tried this but the records keep appearing again after the last one.